# How can I bind F12 in serial-term mode to minicom's F12?

Tags: key-bindings, term

When I use emacs serial-term mode
Can I invoke F12 or other function keys as minicom's F12?

I tried below... but it doesn't work

```
(global-set-key [f12] nil)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Call `describe-key`, enter `f12` and show output.

Comment: @artscan That would be completely pointless.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' After your answer - absolutely completely. )) I just wanted to start conversation and may be to adapt the case https://github.com/boykov/eab-spacemacs/blob/master/keybindings.el#L998 with `(term-send-raw-string "\C-r")` known to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input of an application running in a terminal consists of characters, not keys. So Minicom doesn't directly see a key <kbd>F12</kbd>. What it sees is an *escape sequence* (which is a string starting with the escape character `?\e`), which it knows represents <kbd>F12</kbd>. See [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work/116630#116630) for more information.

Therefore you need to instruct Emacs to send the escape sequence for <kbd>F12</kbd> when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>. The code of term mode has examples of how to do it for other function keys that are predefined in this way. For example, press <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> in Term mode to see what the <kbd>Left</kbd> key does:

```
<left> runs the command term-send-left (found in term-raw-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘term.el’.
```

Its definition is:

```lisp
(defun term-send-left  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\eOD"))
```

Now you need to find the escape sequence to send for <kbd>F12</kbd>.

- One way to do this is to use another terminal (not Emacs-based) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> at a shell prompt. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> causes the next character (which is the escape character that starts the escape sequence) to be entered literally rather than interpreted as a command (to start an escape sequence). You'll see `^[[24~`, where `^[` is a visual representation of the escape character.
- Another way to do this is to run Emacs in a terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>. Here too, you'll see `^[[24~` where `^[` is a visual representation of the escape character.
- Alternatively, you can look up how Emacs does the translation. This information is terminal-specific, but all modern terminals are based on the same standard and xterm is the de facto reference implementation of that standard. Run `M-x load-library RET term/xterm RET` then look up the definition of the variable `xterm-function-map` (`f1 v xterm-function-map RET` then follow the link to the source)¹.

Now that you've identified the escape sequence, bind it in `term-raw-map`.

```
(defun term-send-f12  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[24~"))
(define-key term-raw-map [f12] 'term-send-f12)
```

In your init file:

```
(defun my-eval-after-load-term ()
  (defun term-send-f12  () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string "\e[24~"))
  (define-key term-raw-map [f12] 'term-send-f12)
  )
(eval-after-load "term" my-eval-after-load-term)
```

¹  <sub>It might be nice to look this up programmatically, but there doesn't seem to be a convenient way. `(where-is-internal [f12] xterm-function-map)` doesn't work (it returns `nil`), [I don't know why](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63242/look-up-the-key-bound-to-a-definition-in-a-specific-keymap-ignoring-indirect-bi).</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, It works well and I learned much!