# Look up the key bound to a definition in a specific keymap, ignoring indirect bindings

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

How can I look up what key(s) are bound to a particular definition in a keymap? Basically the converse of `lookup-key`.

[`where-is-internal`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Scanning-Keymaps.html#index-where_002dis_002dinternal) is almost the answer I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases.

```lisp
(defvar my-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key my-map [1] 'one)
(define-key my-map [2] [two])
(list (where-is-internal 'one my-map)
      (where-is-internal [two] my-map))
```

Expected result:

```
(([1]) ([2]))
```

Actual result (with Emacs 26.3):

```
(([1]) nil)
```

It seems that `where-is-internal` can't find a definition that is a vector. A list works, so it's not because the definition is compared with `eq` (and checking the source code, it does use `Fequal`). I guess that a vector is interpreted as an indirect binding of some kind, but passing non-nil values for the `noindirect` and `no-remap` parameters (`(where-is-internal [two] my-map nil t t)`) doesn't help.